# Disable SearchView icons from changing

Tags: android, searchview

I have a SearchView that is starting a new fragment. However, every time I'm back pressing from the fragment, my searchView is showing the EditText field, and the mic button.

Can I have my SearchView be able to start my new fragment (meaning that it's clickable) but without changing any view of the SearchView.

After coming back to my SearchView from my Fragment:

**I would like to see this:**

[image]

And Not the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my thread question. I would like to share it just in case someone else needs it:

I have put the following code in my `onCreateView` method

```
            searchView = (SearchView) mToolBar.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            searchView.setQueryHint("");

            SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchIconText = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)
                    searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
            searchIconText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```